# Will "SELECT CURDATE()" return multiple values on a sufficiently long query across days?

Tags: mysql, date

It's 11:59 PM. You run a query `SELECT CURDATE(), ...` which takes 5 minutes to run. Some rows are evaluated today, some tomorrow. Will the result set include multiple values (today and tomorrow) for `CURDATE()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) clearly states:

> Functions that return the current date or time each are evaluated **only once per query at the start of query execution.** This means that multiple references to a function such as NOW() within a single query always produce the same result. ... This principle also applies to CURDATE(), CURTIME(), UTC_DATE(), UTC_TIME(), UTC_TIMESTAMP(), and to any of their synonyms.

---

So the answer is: the result set will include a single value and it will be "today" (the date of query execution start).